# Ubuntu 12.04 X configuration for FITPC

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

After upgrading my FITPC2 from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 there are now video problems...

1. (OK) GRUB menu appears OK in 1920x1080 resolution - choose Ubuntu
2. (OK) Ubuntu boot up screen with cycling dots appears OK in 1920x1080 resolution and the drum sound is heard
3. (BAD) Screen goes blank and monitor goes to standby after reporting no image. Keyboard is live though.

The only way then of moving forwards is this:-

1. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get a terminal session and log in as root
2. ps -ef | grep 'X' to find the X task. It looks like this: *X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none*
3. kill -9 the X task after which the screen goes blank and then the GUI logon window appears albeit in 1024x768 resolution
4. Logon works ok but the only resolution on offer is 1024x768 when normally it would be 1920x1080

I've tried various ways to get around this, including downloading an xconf setup from the FITPC2 web support site and placing it first in the sequence in the /usr/share/X11/xconf.conf.d/ folder but nothing makes any difference.

I believe that in the previous version of Ubuntu X was configured purely through configuration files and that in Ubuntu 12.04 it use auto-configuration with no conf files unless you wish to use some to override its behaviour.

Does anyone know how to fix this [a] so that it boots correctly to the desktop and [b] so that the desktop uses 1920x1080 resolution?

Regards
SteveM

Answer (score 0):

How did you upgrade to 12.04? Did you use the upgrade manager? I was having a similar problem. I upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 using the upgrade manager on a Fit-PC2 myself. I was able to resolve the issue by installing directly from a flash drive using an image of 12.04.

If you are unsure how to do that. Follow this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/150082/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-usb-pen-drive

Comment: I used the upgrade manager. I also burned a disc from the ISO image but was unable to use that for installation as it said that the FIT-PC needed PAE (Physical Address Extension) so presumably the FIT-PC2 doesn't support that?

I've got some spare flash drives so I'll try that and see if it works. 

My FIT-PC2 is dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu so hopefully I shall find that I can upgrade from a flash drive without destroying the dual boot setup?